# UEFI programming: How to Initialize a CHAR16 Unicode String?

Tags: c, string, unicode, uefi

I have to use some char16-wide strings for uefi programming. How can I initialize them easily?
CHAR8 is easy:

```
CHAR8 *Str = "yehaw\0";
```

CHAR16 meanwhile is hard working that way, therefore I chose this initialization:

```
CHAR16 *Str;
Str = AllocatePool(6*2); //AllocatePool allocates bytewise
Str = ('y','e','h','a','w','\o');
```

So question is what would be the right and easiest way to initialize CHAR16 strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the c standard library and are using a conformant C/C++ compiler, typically prefixing a string with L works for declared strings.As in :

```
 CHAR16 *Str =  L"yehaw";
```

works. However, why not use the ubiquitously accepted type of

```
 wchar_t
```

?

Comment: Note: `wchar_t` is not necessarily  16-bit.

Comment: In UEFI programing the standard library is not available. So i try to stick to the types UEFI want to have

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CHAR16 *Str = u"yehaw\0";
```

Comment: This should be used over `L"yehaw"`, as `CHAR16` is guaranteed to be `UINT16`, which is `uint16_t` for UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

> "An array with element type compatible with a qualified or unqualified version of wchar_t, char16_t, or char32_t may be initialized by a wide string literal with the corresponding encoding prefix (L, u, or U, respectively)" C11 §6.7.9 15

If `CHAR16` is a same as `char16_t`, use

```
Str = u"yehaw";
```